# How to Schedule Cronjobs for start of every month and year

Tags: php, plugin-development, html, wp-cron, cron

I have been trying to run a function at first of every month, and first of every year. And i wanted to run at 12am exact. Below I have shown the function. When is schedule it for daily it works perfectly, but if I try to run it monthly or yearly, it breaks.

I feel that it can be that there is no facility to run yearly. Nevertheless below is the code, please help me run it at start of each month and each year

function Milyin_Admin_Mail(){
    $authors=get_users();
    foreach($authors as $author){

```
$author_posts = get_posts( array('author' => $author->id, 'numberposts' => -1 )); 
 // needed to collect the total sum of views
$counter = 0; 
$word_count=0;
$image_count=0;
$comment_count=0;

$monthly_Views= date("m-Y") . '-Views';
$monthly_Words=date("m-Y") .'-Words'; 
$monthly_Images=date("m-Y") .'-Images';
$monthly_Comments=date("m-Y") .'-Comments';
$monthly_View_Pay=date("m-Y") .'-View-Pay';
$monthly_Word_Pay=date("m-Y") .'-Word-Pay';
$monthly_Image_Pay=date("m-Y") .'-Image-Pay';
$monthly_Comment_Pay=date("m-Y") .'-Comment-Pay';
$monthly_Total_Pay=date("m-Y") .'-Total-Pay';


// do stuff to get author name
 foreach ( $author_posts as $post ) { 
$views = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Creation_Views', true ) ); 
$word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID )));
$image_count = count( get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID ) );
$comment_count = get_comments_number($post->ID) ;

$counter += $views;
$word_counter += $word_count;
$image_counter += $image_count;
$comment_counter += $comment_count;
}
$id= $author->id;
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Views, $counter);
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Words, $word_counter);
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Images, $image_counter);
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Comments, $comment_counter);
$View_Pay = ($counter/1000)*400;
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_View_Pay, $View_Pay);
$Word_Pay= ($word_counter/1000)*10;
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Word_Pay, $Word_Pay);
$Image_Pay= ($image_counter/1000)*10;
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Image_Pay, $Image_Pay);
$Comment_Pay= ($comment_counter/1000)*10;
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Comment_Pay, $Comment_Pay);
$Total_Payment= $View_Pay + $Word_Pay + $Image_Pay+ $Comment_Pay;
update_user_meta($id, $monthly_Total_Pay, $Total_Payment);
$counter = 0;
$word_counter = 0;
$image_counter = 0;
$comment_counter = 0;
}
 }
add_action('Milyin_Daily', 'Milyin_Admin_Mail');
```

Here's the code for the cronjob i wrote for daily, but as soon as i replace it with the word monthly things break

```
function Daily_Counter_Cron() { 
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'Milyin_Daily' ) ) { 
wp_schedule_event( strtotime('00:00:00'), 'daily', 'Daily_Counter' ); }
 } 
add_action('wp', 'Daily_Counter_Cron');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need it on the first day of the month, you should still run this daily.  Just be sure to check if "today" is the first of the month.  Even your "first day of the year" would be executed if it is the first day of the month.

You can check this with the following:

```
$dtFirst = new DateTime('first day of this month');
$dtToday = new DateTime('today');

$interval = $dtToday->diff($dtFirst);

// format('%a') produces total 'days' from DateTime::diff()
if ($interval->format('%a') == '0'){
   // Do your stuff here...
}
```

Doing this check daily will avoid issues with leap years, etc., without significant impact to your server.

I would also recommend you [use a system cron to replace the WP Cron](https://www.iceablethemes.com/optimize-wordpress-replace-wp_cron-real-cron-job/), to ensure you get a proper execution.  WP Cron is too dependant on user activity.

Comment: I think that your approach will keep checking in background, and therefore eat my site's resources making it slow... Is it so?

Comment: Not possible, if you switch to a system cron with “daily” schedule.  It will only check once each day … at midnight, according to your schedule.

Comment: Ok thanks, that seems to be perfect. Thanks for the solution

Comment: To clarify … you would place my code inside Milyin_admin_mail(), wrapping your existing code. So, it could only fully execute on the first day of each month.

Comment: Yep, I understand that, K shall let you know if it doesn't work on first of next month, but still it seems to be the perfect solution. Thanks for answering